# Android :Is it possible to read deleted contacts programmatically?

Tags: android, contacts

I wanted to know if it is possible to read the android contact, which is deleted. By mistake, my contacts are deleted from my Android device. I thought of writing an application which recovers user's deleted contacts. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The delete operation, does not immediately delete a raw contacts row. Instead, it sets the ContactsContract.RawContactsColumns.DELETED flag on the raw contact and removes the raw contact from its aggregate contact.
check official docu here:-
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts